# SQL Server 2012: integer values inserted in varchar column show up with scientific notation

Tags: sql-server, data-conversion

I have a table that stores `INTEGER` numbers in a `VARCHAR` column and it seems some values have been converted to the scientific notation.

```
SELECT [Sales Key], cast(cast([Sales Key] as real) as float)  
FROM <table>
where [Sales Key] = '3.11886e+008'
```

outputs

```
Sales Key   ConvertedValue
3.11886e+008    311886016
```

However,

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
where [Sales Key] = '311886016'
```

returns nothing.

Can someone pls help me understand this behaviour? 3.11886e+008 looks like a rounded down representation of 311886016 but why does the second query fail to return anything?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
select cast(cast('3.11886e+008' as real) as bigint) as Number
Number
311886016
```

shouldn't actually output 311886000?

This initial conversion made me wonder if any type casting is involved when the queries are run.

Comment: In a varchar column, the search is a string matching, not a integer value matching.

Comment: Why are you surprised that '3.11886e+008' <> '311886016'?

Comment: So the value stored in the database column is actually '3.11886e+008'?

Comment: Yes, that is why your first query with `where [Sales Key] = '3.11886e+008'` returned the results. Else nothing would have been returned

Comment: fix the real problem! Don't store ints in a varchar column!!!! It's an int. The clue for the datatype is in the word int! :)

Comment: Then why does '3.11886e+008' convert to 311886016? It should obviously return 311886000, right?

Comment: Please read from @aaronbertrand [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because when you write the SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
where [Sales Key] = '311886016'
```

Its trying to compare the characters `'3.11886e+008'` with `'311886016'` which will not match.

Comment: Indeed, but then why does the initial SELECT convert '3.11886e+008' to 311886016 when it should actually return 311886000?

Comment: it's looks to be because of difference when conversion between `real` and `float`. See this `select cast(cast('3.11886e+008' as real) as float), cast('3.11886e+008' as real),cast('3.11886e+008' as float)`

Comment: `real` uses lesser bytes than `float` and can cause rounding issues, which is what you are seeing here.

Comment: I understand now. Real - float(24) - does not have enough precision. float(53) should have been used. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a varchar column, the search is a string matching, not a integer value matching.

You could use this (but it will be quite slow):

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
where cast(cast([Sales Key] as real) as float) = 311886016
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the real problem is that you are using the wrong data type, but chances are you can't change that now. Just search through it like a Varchar.

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE [Sales Key] LIKE '311886016%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The drawback of Alexander's example (I don't have enough reputation to be allowed to comment his answer) is the unability to use an index (if there is one).

Better use the following query (if the value is always stored in scientific notation):

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
where [Sales Key] = format(311886016, 'E')
```